# Where is webapps in tomcat 7?

Tags: deployment, tomcat7, war, ubuntu-13.10

I am a erlang chicago boss developer, I have been asked to install a tomcat and deploy 2 war files to start the website.

I installed it using [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/tomcat.html) :

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Now he has sent me some files which include menu.war and dashboard.war

Here it is referred as `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` in  [How do I deploy a WAR file in Tomcat?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=123229)'

Can someone tell me where is my `$TOMCAT_HOME` directory?

```
$ echo $TOMCAT_HOME
```

Command is not displaying anything!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Once you are done with tomcat installation using sudo apt-get install tomcat7, its for sure that it has installed somewhere in your machine say it under /opt or the path you have specified while installing.

Go to tomcat installation directory and this path has to be set as environment variable(TOMCAT_HOME). Even you leave it doesn't matter.

You can very well copy the 2 war files inside the webapps directory under tomcat folder.

EX: If you install tomcat7 under /opt, then /opt/tomcat7/webapps is place where you have to deploy the war files.